# Custom task pane height not fully expanded empty space remains

Tags: c#, excel, excel-dna, customtaskpane

I have problem with height of custom task pane in Excel. This task pane is created from Excel AddIn which is created using Excel-Dna library.

When docked to the left side with `MsoCTPDockPosition.msoCTPDockPositionLeft` it does not take the full height but there is an empty space. This happens when an area with internal information is displayed on top of the worksheet window.

[image]

I saw when I resize *manually* the custom task pane window, the custom task pane height changes so it fills the whole space and the extra free space disappears.

---

Q: Is it possible to programmatically force the custom task pane to repaint/refresh so it takes the full height?

Q: Is it somehow possible to set up the custom task pane or the user control which it contains so it takes the full height when docked to the left?

---

Properties of the user control which is inside of the custom task pane has default values, nothing special.
In the code the `Dock` of the user control is set to `DockStyle.Fill`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is out of your control. The [CustomTaskPane.Width](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.customtaskpane.width?view=vsto-2017) property can only be set if the `DockPosition` property is `Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoCTPDockPosition.msoCTPDockPositionRight` or `Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoCTPDockPosition.msoCTPDockPositionLeft`.

To refresh the view (invalidate the UI) you are free to use Windows API functions as well as setting the `Width` property. If you try to set the `Height` property you may end up with a `COMException`.

Comment: Yes you are right but all that I know already from docu, thanks anyway.

Comment: There is no other trivial way to fix that. Try using Windows API functions to invalidate the pane.